# AngularJS ng-if inside transcluded directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use `ng-if` to dynamically include content in the DOM inside a directive I am writing. There is a lot of code here so I am going to include links to JSFiddles. In my [first example](http://jsfiddle.net/dschu012/9uT8X/) I use

```
template:'<div class="step-content"><div ng-show="isCurrentStep" ng-transclude></div>
```

and the scope gets transcluded fine. However in my [second example](http://jsfiddle.net/dschu012/9uT8X/1/) I use

```
template:'<div class="step-content"><div ng-if="isCurrentStep" ng-transclude></div>
```

and I no long have access to my model defined in the controller. The reason I need to use `ng-if` is because on my second step of the wizard I would like to include an `iframe` where the `src` depends on values defined in my model. If I use `ng-show` the `iframe` is included in the DOM and fires a request before my model has been populated with data.

Comment: you can give ng-src a try, for the iframe's source, docs:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Comment: @crisbeto The `iframe` still get's included in the DOM. I guess thinking about it, I might be able to use `ng-if` on the `iframe` itself to control when it is ready to be rendered. But still would like to know why `ng-if` isn't working for me here.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but maybe ng-if is creating a new child scope, so you could also try `ng-if="$parent.isCurrentStep"`

Comment: @crisbeto sorry, I think my last comment might of been confusing. The `ng-if="isCurrentStep"` works, however the scope isn't transcluded. I no longer have access to my `user` model

Comment: I don't see a way other than [one presented here](http://jsfiddle.net/9uT8X/2/), meaning that you need to map isolate scope property to parent scope.

Comment: @nrodic seems like a good enough solution for what I need.